# Burning Uniswap LP tokens

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

There has been something bothering me about LP tokens and I can’t seem to find the answer.

Say I make my own token and raise $1000 in ETH in presales (less gas fees). Then say I want to add my remaining tokens + the ETH I raised to an LP on uniswap. In so doing I get LP tokens, so far so good.

Now however say I want to
1-effectively disown my ability to ever retrieve my addition of liquidity and
2-remove the LP tokens from collecting a portion of the .3% fees.
That is, I want to be as if the tokens never existed.
I see a lot of coins that claim they simply “burned” their LP tokens, but does that just mean they sent it to a dead wallet? Wouldn’t those tokens still be collecting .3% fees, thus incurring deflation?

Please advise!